# Multiple if statements to calculate numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, conditional

Need to calculate numbers from columns when status changes in other columns. Column one has the number of hour assigned for shift 1. Column two has status of completion,  this repeats for 10 shifts. When each shift is marked complete,  I want to add the number form each shifts assigned hours to a calculate column. This gives me the first assigned hours  `=IF([1 Status]="complete",[# of hours 1])`

I am not sure how to start to add each of the consecutive hour as each status is changed to complete. Here are a couple of my attempts. It goes with out saying I am new to SharePoint. All help is appreciated

```
=IF([1 Status]="complete",[# of hours 1])=IF([2 Status]="complete",+[# of hours 2])


=IF([1 Status]="complete",[# of hours 1]
   ,if([1 Status],[2 Status]= "complete",[# of hours 1]+[# of hours 2]))


=if([1 Status]="complete"
    ,[# of hours 1])
    ,if([2 Status]= "complete"
        ,[# of hours 1]+[# of hours 2]))
```

Comment: Does the status change happen sequentially like  [1 Status] is set Complete and then [2 Status] is set to Complete, but [4 status] can't be set before [3 Status] is set, right?

Comment: Correct must be complete sequentially.  But if one is missed I need it to continue to calculate the next one.  So 1 and 2 are completed and 3 the shift is missed and then 4 is completed.  I would want it to add 1, 2, & 4

Comment: Posted the formula.. let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 1):

See the formula and as screenshot showing test results below. I have used S1, S2, .. for the status column names and H1, H2.. for the Hour column names. You would need to replace them with your actual column names.

Also, status selection should be sequential for this to work. If it breaks, the total would be calculated to zero (0)

```
=IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2<>"complete"),S3<>"complete"),S4<>"complete"),S5<>"complete"),S6<>"complete"),S7<>"complete"),S8<>"complete"),S9<>"complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3<>"complete"),S4<>"complete"),S5<>"complete"),S6<>"complete"),S7<>"complete"),S8<>"complete"),S9<>"complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1+H2,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3="complete"),S4<>"complete"),S5<>"complete"),S6<>"complete"),S7<>"complete"),S8<>"complete"),S9<>"complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1+H2+H3,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3="complete"),S4="complete"),S5<>"complete"),S6<>"complete"),S7<>"complete"),S8<>"complete"),S9<>"complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1+H2+H3+H4,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3="complete"),S4="complete"),S5="complete"),S6<>"complete"),S7<>"complete"),S8<>"complete"),S9<>"complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1+H2+H3+H4+H5,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3="complete"),S4="complete"),S5="complete"),S6="complete"),S7<>"complete"),S8<>"complete"),S9<>"complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3="complete"),S4="complete"),S5="complete"),S6="complete"),S7="complete"),S8<>"complete"),S9<>"complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6+H7,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3="complete"),S4="complete"),S5="complete"),S6="complete"),S7="complete"),S8="complete"),S9<>"complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6+H7+H8,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3="complete"),S4="complete"),S5="complete"),S6="complete"),S7="complete"),S8="complete"),S9="complete"),S10<>"complete"),H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6+H7+H8+H9,IF(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(AND(S1="complete",S2="complete"),S3="complete"),S4="complete"),S5="complete"),S6="complete"),S7="complete"),S8="complete"),S9="complete"),S10="complete"),H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6+H7+H8+H9+H10,0))))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try.